# How do I install bumblebee and CUDA?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, bumblebee, cuda

I'm trying to get CUDA running on my Dell Precision M6700 laptop.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 for the moment but I can switch to a newer version if it facilitates the installation of CUDA.

I just want CUDA to run, I don't really care about power management.

After some reading I decided to install bumblebee because my laptop uses Optimus, I followed the instructions here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee
I also updated the drivers to nvidia-319 driver.

Now I am unable to boot my computer with graphics; I end up with a frozen prompt. I still have access to the terminal prompt in recovery mode but I don't know where to look for errors.

I tried things like apt-get remove --purge nvidia* etc.
How can I get the graphic mode working again to try something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I reinstalled a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 to get everything working again. I followed nVidia instructions here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/

- Replace `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop` with `sudo service lightdm stop`
- Don't forget the `--optimus` option when calling the .run
- When exporting to the path, be careful with versions, cuda-5.0 doesn't
  exist if you install cuda 5.5 !
- I did nothing with the `/dev/nvidia*` files. I did not understand that part but CUDA is working.

Check that CUDA is working with the example and it should work !

Comment: What about screen tearing? does that work OK?

Comment: No tearing on main screen, but there is tearing on any additional screen